# Hiding/Showing stage elements when using drag and drop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I asked a question about drag and drop a few days ago, which was answered here:

[Changing text dynamically with drag / drop in Flash CS6 (AS3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869325/changing-text-dynamically-with-drag-drop-in-flash-cs6-as3)

I have another question related to the first question, not sure if I was supposed to ask it on that original question or start a new one.

Anyway, I am trying to have some stage elements show on the screen when the slider is being used, and then hide when the user stops using ("drops") the slider button. The elements are a button and a textarea component.

I set the alpha for each element to zero and then wanted to use as3 to tell the system when to set the alpha to 100, and then of course when to set it back to zero.

The issue I'm having is that when I let go of the slider, everything becomes hidden again EXCEPT for the text inside the textarea component.

Here is my code:

```
 slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);

    function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        slider.startDrag(false, rectangle);
        graphic.alpha = 1;
        textarea1.alpha = 1;
    }

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _onEnterFrame);
    function _onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {

        if (slider.x > 26){
            textarea1.text = '25+';
        }
    }


    slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);

    function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        slider.stopDrag();
        graphic.alpha = 0;
        textarea1.alpha = 0;
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's odd what you say because your code is fine, but could you share your fla ?

Comment: Is the font you are using embedded? That may be the issue. If it still persists, try to set visible = false instead of alpha 0. If no change, simply set the text to "" (empty string) and store the original text in a variable. You should not be setting the textarea1.text in every frame either (check your enterframe) and your MOUSE_UP listener should not be on the slider but on the stage. //<-- pratical tips

Comment: Just to follow up, I ended up using the "" (empty string) solution. I did read somewhere that using embedded fonts or changing the Blend mode would work (??)...